# Python math module grad

Tags: python, numpy, trigonometry, gon

I am trying to use the basic sin, cos, arctan, etc function from numpy, but I want to use gradians. I have search the doc without success, and search for other python modules without luck. Any suggestion on a python module i could use?

Or a function that will work. I have tried different methods to convert grad to rad and back to grad again, but no-one is working.

Comment: Gradians are not the standard way to return an angle measure for any of the big math libraries as far as I know.. (see [libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/index.html) or more specifically [libm](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Mathematics.html)) you'll have to make your own functions to convert..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one should be fine !

```
def gradFromRad(rad):
    return 200*rad/math.pi
def radFromGrad(grad):
    return math.pi*grad/200
```

Comment: don't you have those reversed? `gradFromRad(pi) = pi*math.pi/200 = 0.0493 not 200`

Comment: I have tried exactly this, but this command (using numpy.pi)
`gradFromRad(np.arctan(radFromGrad(100)))`
and it returns 63.91 instead of 99.36.
What am i missing?

Comment: what are you trying to do ? arctan is the inverse function of tan, it outputs an angle given a tan value.

Comment: If write `gradFromRad(math.atan((100)))` i get 99.36 witch is correct. How can this be? i though math.atan() used rads? Now i input gon to atan() and it returns rad which i can convert back to gon.

Comment: the input of atan is not an angle. It's the value of tan given an angle. The output is a value between -pi/2 and pi/2. You can do this test - which does not make any functional sense, but it will let you understand the meaning of these functions - gradFromRad(math.atan(math.tan(pi/4)) and the result should be the converted pi/4 in grad.